# symfony 2 + soap

Tags: web-services, soap, symfony

I try to make a soap service with symfony 2, as a result I have this:

```
     <trace>at Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Debug\ErrorHandler->handle('2', 'SoapFault::SoapFault() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given', '/var/www/Symfony/src/Acme/TxBundle/Controller/DefaultController.php', '39', array('ref' => '333', 'stockinfos' => null))  in  line</trace>
```

my function:

```
 public function getInformationStockAction($ref)
{
      $stockinfos = $this->container->get('doctrine')->getRepository('TxBundle:LlxProduct')->findOneBy(array('ref'=>$ref))
  ;


     if (!$stockinfos)
    {
       throw new \SoapFault(sprintf('No warehouse found for the given productRef : "%s" ', $ref ));

         }

       return $this->container->get('besimple.soap.response')->setReturnValue($stockinfos);
```

}

someone have an idea? thx

Answer (score 1):

As the [documentation](https://www.php.net/soapfault) for `SoapFault` suggests, you need to provide 2 parameters when creating the exception:

```
$faultCode = "yourCode"; // must be a string

throw new \SoapFault(
    $faultCodeHere, // This is the parameter you're missing :-)
    sprintf('No warehouse found for the given productRef : "%s" ', $ref)
);
```